# Why does Spring allow controller annotated request mappings on private methods?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Just came accross this today in a Spring MVC cotnroller class,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/foo/*" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
    private String doThing(final WebRequest request) {
        ...
        return "jsp";
    }
```

This is making it a bit harder to write a test, I'll probably change it to public but what's the point of allowing mappings on private methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does not provide a mechanism for limiting the target of annotations based on access modifier.

Comment: Of course, so there's nothing stopping you from adding them to private methods.

Comment: Technically true, however Spring could throw an exception when encountering a private method being annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

As **@smp7d** stated, Java does not limit the target of annotations based on access modifiers, but syntactically speaking, **@RequestMapping** should not work on private methods. Also we cannot limit this, since it would break the backward compatibility. So, you can either go for defining your methods as **public** or you can create your own custom implementation.

Take a look at this: [Spring's @RequestMapping annotation works on private methods](https://sebastian.marsching.com/blog/archives/149-Springs-RequestMapping-annotation-works-on-private-methods.html)